# Mark Labels Not Displaying In Tableau 2018

Tags: tableau-api

Others have asked this question before, but no one has provided an actual answer to it. I can't get all of the marks/labels to display in my Tableau visualizations.

Selecting "allow labels to overlap" does not fix the problem. That displays several hidden labels for the smallest of the areas, and it places those labels at the top of the bars, ignoring the formatting that sets the labels to the bottom. However, whether or not that option is checked, the empty areas in the screen shot stay empty. And those areas are clearly large enough to display the missing labels without encroaching on any other label.

I'm guessing this is a bug in Tableau because there's no reasonable explanation as to why this is happening, but I'm new to Tableau and unsure how to address this.

[image: Screen Shot of Tableau with Missing Fields]

Comment: "enter image description here" links to screen shot.

Answer (score 1):

While I can offer no explanation, this has been a reported problem for several years. Tableau's own documentation states to check the Allow marks to overlap checkbox, yet that doesn't always work.

I don't know if it's a bug so much as it is a complicated calculation for the rendering engine to determine what will and won't fit into a space. To the human eye it will fit but it's possible the underlying calculations inside Tableau don't see it that way. I find that particularly on dual-axis charts (like yours) this happens more frequently. I've done two things to get around it when it comes up:

1. Change font family or font size
2. Put more info into the tooltips so the end user sees the data when they hover.

If you wish to pursue this as a bug, you will need to contact Tableau Support and file a case. They will ask you to submit a twbx file to reproduce the issue.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Changing font to Automatic solved the problem for me (Tableau Desktop 10.5)

Answer (score 1):

Label -> Font -> Automatic solved the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

You can select individual marks, right click to pop up a menu, and specify whether to always hide or always show the labels for the selected marks (overriding the default behavior)